# Using only GetAllTargets.php Vuforia Web Services

Tags: php, web, vuforia

Hello I am making a site and want to list all targets in Vuforia Cloud Database. I am using the PHP samples but can't list targets without SampleSelector.php file can anyone help me to use only GetAllTargets.php

[GetAllTargets.php](https://github.com/thirunar/vuforia-web-services/blob/master/php/GetAllTargets.php)

[SampleSelector.php](https://github.com/thirunar/vuforia-web-services/blob/master/php/SampleSelector.php)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple library with a function to delete all targets from the cloud database. But at first it gets all targets. Maybe you can have a look on it.
https://github.com/FionNoir/VuforiaClient

The function should look like that:

```
public function getAllTargets() {
        $ch = curl_init(self::BASE_URL . self::TARGETS_PATH);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $this->getHeaders('GET'));
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
        $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
        if ($info['http_code'] !== 200) {
            die('Failed to list targets: ' . $response . "\n");
        }
        $targets = json_decode($response);
    }
```

Comment: I've added the function 'getAllTargets'. It should work, but I havn't tried